# Not getting reputation points for suggested edits

Tags: support, reputation, suggested-edits

I think the reputation system is broken...

I have edited some questions and tags (TeX main site) and I do not have received the corresponding pontuation.

Am I wrong?

**EDIT**: Today I have only 54 points

[image]

Question edited:

[image]

Tag edited:

[image]

Activity today:

[image]

Comment: There is a reputation cap of 200 per day. See [Upvote without getting any reputation](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1783)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To date (2013-05-07) you have submitted 574 Suggested Edits for approval, 512 of which were accepted while 62 were declined. [Back in Feb 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77505/168244), the reputation system was updated to award a suggestor with +2 reputation in the case of an approved Suggested Edit. This should put your tally of reputation accumulated via this method at +1,024.

Now, according to [the way suggested edits work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76251/168244), you're only allowed 1,000 reputation in total for approved Suggested Edits. However, when posts are deleted, you lose the revision reputation. Here's a quick take on reputation associated with Suggested Edits (from the above post):

> #### Can I earn reputation?
>
> - When a suggested edit is approved, the user who suggested it gets +2 reputation. The regular daily reputation cap applies, and the total cap is 1,000. Like any other reputation, the +2 is deleted if the edited post is ever deleted.
> - When a suggested edit is rejected, no penalty is given.

A quick aggregation of [your reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13907/papiro?tab=reputation) lists at least 484 edits still "visible" from non-deleted posts (out of around 579 post-related reputation earnings). While 484 visible, approved Suggested Edits drops you back to earning *only* 968 reputation, you may have reached the 1,000 rep-cap over all time (512 approved + 484 visible - 500 maximum ~ 500 posts = 1,000 reputation). Once you've reached this, there's no more bonuses from Suggested Edits.

This is just my guess... `:)`

<sub>While this may seem anti-climatic, continue to help improve the site!</sub>

Comment: @Papiro While I really appreciate your contribution please don't edit for the sake of editing. Don't just remove thanks but combine it with other aspects too. Removing thanks is a SO habit I agree, but it's not well-respected here. Some of us actually don't find it helpful. So reemphasizing again, please combine the thanks removing business with other issues with the post such as retagging, rewording etc. And please leave a reason why you removed it. Here is my longer reasoning http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3503/welcome-page-needs-more-welcoming

Comment: @percusse The reason to remove "thanks":`[Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.`, from  (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks). But I agree with your considerations.

Comment: @Papiro That's the official announcement of the stackoverflow however it is unfounded and proven to be amplifying hostility over time judging from the user behavior on TeX-SX and SO. Another detail is that we don't remove *Any help is appreciated* type of comments which are also against conciseness but somehow neglected. On the contrary these are left intact which is awkward the least. *Thanks* or other signs of appreciation are actually what makes the question complete in some cases though when left out the question assumes a dictating tone which is asking for trouble.